# Python Push an HTML to Github

Tags: python, git

I have an html map made with plotly and I would like to push it to Github. My main page has been set to gitpages so that the map can viewed.

The code runs automatically every day thus the map needs to be pushed to GitHub every day as part of my Python code.

```
repo = g.get_user().get_repo('research_project')
#Index being the interactive map
file_list = [
    index
]
file_name = ["index.html"]
commit_message = 'python update 2'

master_ref = repo.get_git_ref('heads/main')
master_sha = master_ref.object.sha
base_tree = repo.get_git_tree(master_sha)
element_list = list()

for i, entry in enumerate(file_list):
    element = InputGitTreeElement(file_name[i], '100644', 'blob',data)
    element_list.append(element)
tree = repo.create_git_tree(element_list, base_tree)
parent = repo.get_git_commit(master_sha)
commit = repo.create_git_commit(commit_message, tree, [parent])
master_ref.edit(commit.sha)
```

I get AssertionError when I try this.

Comment: Add whole error traceback, as it is hard to know where it is failing.

Comment: Are you using pygit2, or some other library? The [tag:git] tag is for command-line Git.

Comment: I am using PyGithub library and the error happens in the following line : element = InputGitTreeElement(file_name[i], '100644', 'blob',data)